# What is the critical ratio of eggs to potatoes between an egg salad and a potato salad?

Tags: eggs, potatoes, salad

It's probably not a one to one ratio. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty pointless question, especially because there's a rather large range of "potato and egg salad" in the middle, and because most people don't put potato in their egg salad.

Comment: Interesting; while I've had many varieties of potato salad with egg in it, I've never had egg salad with potatoes in it...

Comment: I'm with @matthias on this one, if I'd put a potato in my egg salad I wouldn't think of it as an egg salad anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 potato to three eggs for egg salad with potato in. Reverse for potato salad with egg in.

Comment: This seems more like a joke than an answer; it's best to say things like this as comments (once you accrue enough rep to do so).

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking at what percentage of potatoes does a formerly egg salad become potato salad and vice versa?

My egg salad recipe does not call for potatoes, but I believe my mom puts maybe two hard boiled eggs for every 6-8 potatoes in her potato salad.

Answer (score 3):

My egg salad has a ratio of 100% eggs, 0% potatoes.  My potato salad has a half dozen eggs to 2 1/2 kilos/5 pounds of potatoes, I chop them fine.  Sometimes I will make pretty eggs and put them on top though, usually sliced thin or quartered, then I use 8 eggs.